# Loopback external api errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have created my external api on loopback, i tried to use the Model.find method and other query methods, it not working for me, what i get is just error message.

Below are the message i get
[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGSUp.png)

After i check it might be my api result problem, because my object is inside another object.
[my api output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79esl.png)

Can some guide me how to solve it, can change the output result?

datasources.js

```
"consumer_model": {
"name": "consumer_model",
"connector": "rest",
"debug": "false",
 "operations": [
   {
     "template": {
       "method": "GET",
       "url": "http://myurl.com/api/v1/consumers",
        "headers": {
          "accepts": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "query": {
          "id": "{id}",
          "firstname": "{firstname}"
        },
        "responsePath": "$.data"
      },
      "functions": {
        "consumer": [
          "id",
          "firstname"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

model-config.js

```
"consumers": {
"dataSource": "consumer_model",
"public": true
}
```

myconsumer.js

```
module.exports = function(consumers) { 

};
```

myconsumer.json

```
{
 "name": "consumers",
 "base": "Model",
 "idInjection": true,
 "options": {
   "validateUpsert": true
 },
 "properties": {},
 "validations": [],
 "relations": {},
 "acls": [],
 "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code, with the model definition etc please.

Comment: As Conradj said please share the code particular you should have a file called "myModels.js" and "myModels.json" in the common/models directory.

Comment: Hi all, thank for replied, i already include my code, could you guide me how to solve this? thank you.

Comment: output i already attached on top, my api output there.

Comment: Hi all, thank for replied, i already include my code on top. output i already attached on top, "my api output" there. Is that because of the output format? because there are two [ ] before my data, normally only output one. if it is because my data format, how i going to solve it, please guide me to solve this errors, appreciate that if you could guide me solve this errors.